# How can I upgrade to Java 1.8 on an Amazon Linux Server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, java, update

I tried sudo yum update but it just keeps java "1.7.0_75". I need 1.8 for it to work with another application but can't figure out how to upgrade it.
Do I need to manually install it somehow? There's not much information on this on the internet as far as I can see.
Specs:

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.5.4.0.53.amzn1-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

When I try update now:

```
[ec2-________]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
No packages marked for update
```

Is there anything else I need to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

To remove java 1.7 and install java 1.8:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Comment: This is correct, thank you. I'm new to this as you can see.

Comment: Changed the order of installation so that it doesn't remove the aws-apitools.

Comment: Note this will only install the Java Runtime.

Comment: @johnnieb you can get the full JDK with this: yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64

Comment: @orange80 I believe the command is `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y`

Comment: @johnnieb the only difference is that your command will make the installer assume yes responses. Not always a good approach.

Comment: This worked perfectly well for Amazon EC2 Instances and i was looking for that only.

Answer (score 153):

Install Java Runtime 1.8

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0
```

or if you need a java compiler and other developer tools:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Then use the alternatives command to make Java 1.8 the default.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config javac
# etc
```

If you prefer you can remove Java 1.7 with

```
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

but remove it **after** you installed Java 1.8 or the aws-apitools will also be removed as they depend on Java on being installed.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. If you follow the accepted answer you will lose aws-apitools.

Comment: +1 for sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java

Comment: I have found some other packages to depend on Java 1.7.0 even though they work with Java 1.8.0, so it might be better to keep the original packages installed.

Answer (score 5):

```
yum install java-1.8.0 -y
/usr/sbin/alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
/usr/sbin/alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac
yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```