# How to upgrade from Java 7 to Java 8 on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, java, amazon-linux

I found [another thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/664643/how-can-i-upgrade-to-java-1-8-on-an-amazon-linux-server) on this that is outdated and doesn't give a non-interactive way to do this. If you need to upgrade from Java 7 to Java 8 to run Jenkins, or whatever other Java application, you can do that by plugging this into a user_data script for Amazon Linux